# Google App Engine Wont work its stuck in cmD

Tags: php, google-app-engine

i just started using Google app engine.I followed the install instruction and am trying to run the simple hello word demo shown on Google's the app engines web-page and for some reason my web server wont start its stuck at

```
C:\Users\princewill\Desktop\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py --php_executable_p
ath=C:\Users\princewill\Desktop\php\php-cgi.exe C:\Users\princewill\Desktop\test
\helloworld
INFO     2013-08-21 06:57:35,788 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Checking for updates
to the SDK.
INFO     2013-08-21 06:57:35,789 __init__.py:94] Connecting through tunnel to: a
ppengine.google.com:443
INFO     2013-08-21 06:57:36,773 sdk_update_checker.py:261] Update check failed:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING  2013-08-21 06:57:36,782 api_server.py:317] Could not initialize images
API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-08-21 06:57:36,786 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http
://localhost:50032
INFO     2013-08-21 06:57:36,789 dispatcher.py:164] Starting module "default" ru
nning at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-08-21 06:57:36,792 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:
http://localhost:8000
```

can anyone help me out please.. this is driving me nuts

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't start? Just visit http://localhost:8000 while it's running.

Comment: It certainly looks like it's running, its listening on 8080 and 8000. You app will be on port 8080 (http://localhost:8080) the admin console on port 8000.  Thats what the log above is telling you.

Comment: Well i tried running localhost a couple of times and its not working says the webpage is not working

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it is stuck. You should load localhost:8080 and once that is loaded go back to your command line prompt to see if there are any errors.  The description of "its not working says the webpage is not working" is not very helpful, exact error messages and log output would be more helpful.